# Why is my program not locating my image file?

Tags: java, oop, jframe, bufferedimage, getresource

So I'm trying to test my `TileC` class, but whenever I run it, it shows the run-time error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!`. I'm not sure why because my path `String Path = "/CourseworkAY/res/NormalSwamp.gif";` seems to be correct?

Here is all of the code within the TileC class:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;



public class TileC extends JPanel {

BufferedImage tileImage;
static JFrame test = new JFrame("Test");
static JPanel userDetailsPanel = new JPanel();

public TileC(BufferedImage img) {
    tileImage = img;
}

 protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {  
        int width = getWidth();  
        int height = getHeight();  
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x += tileImage.getWidth()) {  
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y += tileImage.getHeight()) {  
                g.drawImage(tileImage, x, y, this);  
            }  
        }  
    }  

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {  
        test.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        String Path = "/CourseworkAY/res/NormalSwamp.gif";

        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(TileC.class.getResource(Path));  
        TileC backgroundImage = new TileC(image); 

        test.setContentPane(backgroundImage);
        test.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        userDetailsPanel.setOpaque(false);
        test.add(userDetailsPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        test.setSize(400,400);
        test.setVisible(true);

    }
```

}

[image: Also here is a screenshot of the related path within the package explorer:]

I've checked lots of other related questions but none of the answers have helped me, can someone shed some light please?

Comment: try with only `res/NormalSwamp.gif`

Comment: I have tried that, throws the same exception?

Comment: "/CourseworkAY/res/NormalSwamp.gif" does not seem to be an absolute valid path, try to get a correct absolute path of the res directory.

Comment: You could also use res/NormalSwamp.gif if you copy your ressources to the build location.

Comment: Care to expand on how to achieve this?

Comment: 1. Don't use default packages. 2. Move your resources into a package. 3. Obtain their path relative to where the classloader looks for classes.

Comment: you mean like "H:/eclipse43/CourseworkAY/res/NormalSwamp.gif"?

Comment: No, that's an absolute path and should not be used with resources. Please note that exact question has been asked many times on this site, and you would be doing yourself and all of us a favor if you would look at a few of the similar questions that are easily found. I'm not sure that we need yet another one posted here.

Comment: [Here are some duplicates](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=java+use+of+resources+getresource+null+site:http:%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F)